# What it means that associated with Class synchronization sentence in java specification

Tags: java

In Java language spec, there is below sentence

> A class method that is declared synchronized synchronizes on the monitor associated with the Class object of the class.

I don't understand this sentence totally even I don't know what I don't know.

Could you let me know this sentence with some examples?

I appreciate you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
synchronized (YourClass.class)


static synchronized
```

Are equivalent, this is what it means.

Or in other words:

```
public static synchronized void go(){

}
```

will acquire the monitor that is associated with a *class*, not with an *instance*, as opposed to :

```
public synchronized void go() {

}
```

that will acquire the monitor from an *instance*.